# jbehave - How to execute code before each example of a scenario

Tags: bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

When using Serenity with JBehave, my step definition adds information provided through @Given and @When into an internal state class, which is validated in @Then methods.

The state class needs to be reinitialized for each test, that is before each scenario without example and before each example of a scenario with examples.

How can I achieve that?

I found a JIRA ticket requesting @BeforeExample (which would solve my problem) at http://jbehave.github.io/Old_JBehave_Issues/548/. However, using @BeforeScenario clears only before each scenario, but not before each example.

Clearing state in each @Given would not work in the cases where a scenario has multiple @Givens (using Given... And....).

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeScenario` does not work (is ignored for scenarios with examples alltogether).

`@BeforeScenario(uponType = ScenarioType.ANY)` does work, which I found not working before posting this question, but was apparently caused by another reason.

Either way, the method must be public.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to reset scenario-state using JBehave's 'Before' LifeCycle:

```
Narrative:
...

Lifecycle: 
Before:
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
```

Some additional Lifecycle options:

```
Lifecycle:
After:
Outcome: ANY    
Given a step that is executed after each scenario regardless of outcome
Outcome: SUCCESS 
Given a step that is executed after each successful scenario
Outcome: FAILURE 
Given a step that is executed after each failed scenario
```

Source: [JBehave Story Syntax](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but if someone get's here, know that there is already a
@BeforeExample and @AfterExample annotation for this purpose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).